# I added this into my product.custom.liquid (section)

Tags: html, configuration, shopify, e-commerce

{% comment %} File upload {% endcomment %}
 Logo

```
        {% comment %} input {% endcomment %}
        <div>
          <label for="custom_business_name">Nom de votre établissement sur Google</label>
          <input required type="text" id="custom_business_name" name="properties[Nom du business]" data-type="add-to-cart-form" />
        </div>
```

But the line items are not displaying in the cart when I add line-items

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code between the `<form> and </form>` tags [product form].

For more you can checkout this reference

https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/line-item-property